# jQuery underestimates the width and height of some elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to draw a spotlight on some page elements during a user interface tutorial (see [CSS3 spotlight effect using a rounded rectangle with gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19361291/586086)).

For example, here's the navbar:

[image]

and spotlighted (rest of the page is dimmed out):

[image]

However, one of the elements on my page is giving me trouble. Here's it's positioning in Chrome:

[image]

However, jQuery thinks it is 330px by 60px:

```
> var blah = $('.user-list')
[
<div class=​"well well-skinny user-list">​…​</div>​
]
> blah.height()
60
> blah.width()
330
```

This results in a spotlight that is too small when it is drawn:

[image]

The weird thing is, there are lots of other elements on the page (like the navbar) whose sizes are calculated correctly, and the spotlight shows them properly.

What is up with this element that causes jQuery to show an incorrect height and width? Some additional information:

- The entire page is on `border-box` sizing except for `input` elements, which don't play well with bootstrap.
- There is 9px padding on all sides with a 1px border, which makes up for the size discrepancy, however there are many other elements with border/padding where the size calculation works properly, and this is the only element that is weird. For example, the bootstrap navbar shown above has 20px of padding on the left and right sides, but the width is calculated correctly.

Comment: What about `outerHeight()` and `outerWidth()` ?

Comment: @f00bar is it possible that `height()` is actually computing `innerHeight()` for this element and `outerHeight()` for other elements? That would be interesting...

Comment: @AndrewMao Its different because of box-sizing property. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

A css width of an element is (according to box-sizing css property)

if(it is border-box)

```
 css width = element content width + padding + border
```

if ( it is padding-box)

```
css width = element content width + padding
```

If(It is content-box , which is by default)

```
css width = element content width
```

and so for height

---

jQuery .width() always give the element content width.

If you want elements width and height with padding you can use `.innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` method.

If you want include border size than use `.outerWidth()` and `.outerHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

Width is poorly explained in many places, however, it is more properly defined as the width of the "context box". More information, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).